# Combine 2 requirements in 1 query

Tags: mysql, sql, checkbox, mariadb

I have an existing PHP project I need to edit. There is also a database with some content.

Some of the tables are organized as follows:

**Table: `tab_col`**

```
Col1
Col2
Col3
...
```

**Table `checkbox`**

```
id   column
1    Col1
2    Col4
...
```

One of the tasks is to displays all columns of `tab_col`. Next to them an input field needs to be placed. If the name of one of the columns from `tab_col` exists in the table `checkbox`, a checkbox is placed next to the name of the column. Otherwise it is a textfield.

So in this case, a checkbox would be placed next to `Col1` and `Col4`.
This is how it should look like: https://jsfiddle.net/e7Lpfs9f/

Actually, I'm only interested in the SQL query.

---

With this query, I get all columns:

```
SHOW columns FROM tab_col
```

But how can I combine both requirements in only 1 query? I don't want to query the database twice.

---

PS: I know, this may not be the best way to store data in the database, but that's what I have to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
SELECT t1.column_name, ch.id
FROM information_schema.Columns t1
LEFT JOIN checkbox ch
  ON t1.column_name = ch.column
WHERE t1.table_name = 'tab_col'
ORDER BY t1.column_name;
```

If `ch.id` is `NULL` then the column isn't in `checkbox`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I was wrong about the 2nd table. The column names are stored in the column `column`.

Comment: @user1170330 hm, I'm not exactly sure what you are talking about. According to [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/information-schema-columns-table/), columns for tables are stored in `column_name`

Comment: Please see my edit. The colomn names in the table `checkbox` are also stored in another column, called `column`.

Comment: Ok, great! Thank you! But what if there's another table, e.g. radiobutton. How to differentiate then?

Comment: Well, I guess you could either JOIN it in and add another column for radiobuttons? Or build the SQL in php depending on what you need...

Answer (score 0):

You can address this with stored procedure

```
WITH CTE1 (
        SELECT column_name
        FROM [DB_NAME].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'tbl_col'
    )

WITH CTE2 (
        SELECT column_name
        FROM [DB_NAME].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'checkbox'
    )

SELECT c1.column_name, 
     CASE ISNULL(c2.column_name,'0')
             WHEN '0' THEN 'checkbox'
             ELSE 'textbox'
     END 
         FROM CTE1 c1
   LEFT JOIN CTE2 c2 on c2.column_name = c1.column_name
```

Thus if there is a match between tbl_col table and checkbox table is it textbox, otherwise it is checkbox